# How do I collect and sum up these values by Class Name

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to add collect all the odds ,loop through the results and add them to array totalArr.
in the second step I tried to sum up the values in the totalArr but its not working. alert(sum)
is returning  03.32.51.82.2

````
    <p class="slip-odds">3.3</p>
    <p class="slip-odds">2.5</p>
    <p class="slip-odds">1.8</p>
    <p class="slip-odds">2.2</p>```


  <script type="text/javascript">

  let getSlipOdds = document.getElementsByClassName('slip-odds');

   let totalArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < getSlipOdds.length; i++) {

   var slipOdd = getSlipOdds[i].innerHTML;
   totalArr.push(slipOdd);

}

let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < totalArr.length; i++) {
    sum += totalArr[i];
}
alert(sum);

 </script>
````

Comment: Try sum += parseFloat(totalArr[i]). Your problem is you're getting them as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to number before pushing to the array like this

```
   totalArr.push(Number(slipOdd));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert totalArr[i] to a number before adding.

Answer (score 1):

it's because javascript thinks it's a string, not a number. you can easily multiply your array elements with 1 and it will convert it to a number

sum += totalArr[i] * 1;